# Error while installing Oracle 12c on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: command-line, bash, oracle

1) Error message: DISPLAY variable not set properly:

oracle@sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:/app/binaries/database$ ./runInstaller Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

Checking Temp space: must be greater than 500 MB.   Actual 415483 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 1927 MB    Passed
***Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors

> > > Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.    Failed <<<<***

Some requirement checks failed. You must fulfill these requirements before

continuing with the installation,

Continue? (y/n) [n] n

User Selected: No

Exiting Oracle Universal Installer, log for this session can be found at /tmp/OraInstall2017-05-02_02-41-55AM/installActions2017-05-02_02-41-55AM.log

2) verified hostname and have set environment variable DISPLAY=hostname:0.0 like below using Oracle user id: (after searching the solutions on google and askubuntu)

oracle@sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:/app/binaries/database$ hostname
sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC
oracle@sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:/app/binaries/database$ echo $DISPLAY
sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:0.0

oracle@sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:~$ env
LANG=en_IN
DISPLAY=sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:0.0
COLORTERM=truecolor
XDG_SESSION_ID=2
USER=oracle
PWD=/app/oracle12c
HOME=/app/oracle12c
MAIL=/var/mail/oracle
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
SHLVL=1
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LOGNAME=oracle
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/502
XAUTHORITY=/home/sreenivas/.Xauthority
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/app/binaries/database
oracle@sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:

3) when i logout and login with "oracle" user again then DISPLAY variable is set to NULL instead of localhost:0.0

sreenivas@sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:~$ su - oracle
Password: 
oracle@sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:~$ echo $DISPLAY
:0

4) I have added DISPLAY variable in .bashrc profile for oracle user and have run .bashrc 
oracle@sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:~$ cat .bashrc
LANG=en_IN
DISPLAY=sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:0.0
COLORTERM=truecolor
XDG_SESSION_ID=2
USER=oracle
PWD=/app/oracle12c
HOME=/app/oracle12c
MAIL=/var/mail/oracle
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
SHLVL=1
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LOGNAME=oracle
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/502
XAUTHORITY=/home/sreenivas/.Xauthority
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin:/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/app/binaries/database

5) But still DISPLAY variable is set again to NULL like below.
oracle@sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:~$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
oracle@sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:~$

Questions) 
a) How do I set environment DISPLAY variable permanently to "sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:0.0" in order to avoid oracle installation error ?
b) Give me the path where to change the DISPLAY variable to above value permanently ? 
I have read many articles but could not able to resolve this error. Pls guide me as it is urgent.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - the value `:0` is not a "null" value for the `DISPLAY` variable (it's the normal value for the primary display on the local host). What do you get if you run `/usr/bin/xdpyinfo` manually?

Comment: root@sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:/tmp# /usr/bin/xdpyinfo
/usr/bin/xdpyinfo:  unable to open display "sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:0.0".
root@sreenivas-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:/tmp#

Comment: Not able to understand the root cause of this issue. I have been working on this issue from past 2 days. I have tried all attempts but could not

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by following below steps..

Comment: step1) root@sreenivas:/usr/lib/jvm# xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
root@sreenivas:/usr/lib/jvm# su - oracle
oracle@sreenivas:~$ cd database
oracle@sreenivas:~/database$ ls -lrt

Comment: oracle@sreenivas:~/database$ set -o vi
oracle@sreenivas:~/database$ ./runInstaller
Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

Checking Temp space: must be greater than 500 MB.   Actual 426627 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 4014 MB    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.    Actual 16777216    Passed
Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2017-05-03_06-12-09PM. Please wait ...oracle@sreenivas:~/database$

Answer (score 0):

step1)

root@sreenivas:/usr/lib/jvm# xhost +

access control disabled, clients can connect from any host

root@sreenivas:/usr/lib/jvm# su - oracle

oracle@sreenivas:~$ cd database

oracle@sreenivas:~/database$ ls -lrt

total 36

-rwxrwxrwx  1 oracle oinstall  500 Feb  6  2013 welcome.html

-rwxrwxrwx  1 oracle oinstall 8533 Jul  7  2014 runInstaller

drwxrwxrwx  2 oracle oinstall 4096 Jul  7  2014 rpm

drwxrwxrwx  2 oracle oinstall 4096 Jul  7  2014 sshsetup

drwxrwxrwx  2 oracle oinstall 4096 Jul  7  2014 response

drwxrwxrwx 14 oracle oinstall 4096 Jul  7  2014 stage

drwxrwxrwx  4 oracle oinstall 4096 May  3 14:50 install

oracle@sreenivas:~/database$ set -o vi

oracle@sreenivas:~/database$ ./runInstaller

Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

Checking Temp space: must be greater than 500 MB.   Actual 426627 MB    Passed

Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 4014 MB    Passed

Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.    Actual 16777216    Passed

Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2017-05-03_06-12-09PM. Please wait ...

oracle@sreenivas:~/database$